# Is it possible to search by regexp with Symfony Dom crawler?

Tags: symfony, parsing, dom, domcrawler

The [Dom Crawler Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) is powerfull to parse html content, in its documentation describes basics selections (like `filter('body > p')`) or more complex xpath like `//span[contains(@id, "article-")]`

Is it possible to fetch elements by regular expression? Maybe something like that is available: `filter('body')->filter('div.*-timeLabel-*')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in XPath 2.0, you can use matches:

```
$crawler->filterXPath("//div[matches(@id, '*-timeLabel-*')]");
```

but if you don't have that available, your best bet is to try and combine some of the other XPath [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions), for example this should do the trick for your case:

```
$crawler->filterXPath("//div[contains(@id, '*-timeLabel-*')]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Modified one of the examples from the docs applying a anonymous function.

```
$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('body')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
    // regex and return $node->attr('class')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but i think the answer is yes cuz the filter method of the crawler calls 
 this method of the `CssSelectorConverter` and according to the documentation you can pass an expression as a parameter

```php
    /**
     * Translates a CSS expression to its XPath equivalent.
     *
     * Optionally, a prefix can be added to the resulting XPath
     * expression with the $prefix parameter.
     *
     * @param string $cssExpr The CSS expression
     * @param string $prefix  An optional prefix for the XPath expression
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function toXPath($cssExpr, $prefix = 'descendant-or-self::')
    {
        return $this->translator->cssToXPath($cssExpr, $prefix);
    }
```